# Wget not downloading image in "href" attribute, but download it correctly in "src" attribute

Tags: html, wget

I got troubles with `wget` and link convertions.

Here is a test little test I made :

Basically I have two images, with 2 different paths, a small one that is displayed in the `<img>` tag, and a larger one that is linked in the `<a>` tag :

```html
<a class="gallery-photo" data-fancybox="gallery" href="http://localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/representations/path-of-large-image/photo.jpg">
  <img class="img-fluid" alt="" src="http://localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/representations/path-of-small-image/photo.jpg">
</a>
```

Now trying to download the page using `wget` and I get as a result :

```html
<a class="gallery-photo" data-fancybox="gallery" href="http://localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/representations/path-of-large-image/photo.jpg">
  <img class="img-fluid" alt="" src="/representations/path-of-small-image/photo.jpg">
</a>
```

As you can see, the `<img>` (small image) was correctly downloaded, and it's `src` attribute correctly converted into a relative path.
But the regarding `href` attribute from the link (large image), the image was not downloaded, and the path remained an absolute path.

I thought that `wget` would convert both `src` and `href` attributes in the same way.

Note that if I edit my source code, and add the image that is in the `href` tag in my HTML in a `<img>` tag just before the `<a>` like this :

```
<img alt="" src="http://localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/representations/path-of-large-image/photo.jpg" style="display:none;">
<a class="gallery-photo" data-fancybox="gallery" href="http://localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/representations/path-of-large-image/photo.jpg">
  <img class="img-fluid" alt="" src="http://localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/representations/path-of-small-image/photo.jpg">
</a>
```

Then the image is found by `wget`, downloaded, and paths are correctly converted in both `src` and `href` attributes.

My `wget` command is the following :

```
wget -T 15 --no-check-certificate -r -l inf -k -nc -nH --no-parent --cut-dirs=2 -m -p -E -e robots=off -P ./ http://localhost:3000/demo/my-website
```

Any idea what's going on ?

Comment: @DiegoD Hi, `-k` is actually an alias for `--convert-links`, so the option is already enabled in my command

Comment: yes indeed I removed my comment in the timespan of few seconds as soon as I realized the -k option was used already. The point is that wget is not expected to download links and make them available locally.. but that option seemed to fulfill the need.. instead it doesn't since the OP already attempted